# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed error with Jquery ajax (post) ONLY when browsed with IE

Tags: php, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm pretty new to the html game, so I apologize if this is too basic...
I've got an email contact form on a web page that I am using JQuery validate to validate and send the email, then remove the form and replace it with a 'thank you' message. It works in all other browsers except IE and I get this 405 error.

My Google-fu is failing me - can anyone help out? Here are the key parts (I think) of the Jquery and the form code. Thanks!!

JQuery

```
 $("#emailform").validate({


        /*stuff*/
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#emailform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#hider').html(data);
            });
            // remove form after submission
            $("#emailform").hide();
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<form name="myform" id="emailform" action="" class="gradient" method="POST">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...this is really kicking my tail.

Edit:Also, if it would help, the page is at www dot precisionnc dot com/installation.html (not actual link because I don't know if that would be kosher to do...thanks again for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, in IE there's a javascript error that shows up.
the problem seems to be with the watermark.
witch cause the javascript to crash.
then your submit handler/validation does not work.
So the problem is that when the code for the watermark is loaded, it's not linked to JQuery in IE.
How to repair? try changing your script load order or update your codebase for it http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/downloads/list

Comment: Also you should check for server-side validation I got a php error most likely because the e-mail was not real (test@test.com)

Comment: Any idea why this is an error in IE only? I've tried about everything I can to fix this, but still no dice. I see the error, but if it was an unsupported why only in IE... too strange...

Comment: Fixed that then. Still don't know why that gives an error in JS only in IE, but I just got rid of the plugin, used the native 'placeholder' values for Firefox/Safari/Chrome and will let IE folks suffer the pain of being IE folks...Thanks for your help!!!